# Windows does not see my command line arguments

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, python, django

```
C:\Users\Drew Gross\Documents\Projects\Batadase\src>django-admin.py startproject batadase
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=all output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Print traceback on exception
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:
  cleanup
  compilemessages
  createcachetable
  dbshell
  diffsettings
  dumpdata
  flush
  inspectdb
  loaddata
  makemessages
  reset
  runfcgi
  runserver
  shell
  sql
  sqlall
  sqlclear
  sqlcustom
  sqlflush
  sqlindexes
  sqlinitialdata
  sqlreset
  sqlsequencereset
  startapp
  startproject
  syncdb
  test
  testserver
  validate

C:\Users\Drew Gross\Documents\Projects\Batadase\src>
```

I don't think this is normal. I can't think of anything I've done recently that would cause this to happen, although I have done a bunch of things, I can't remember them all. It did work in the past.

Comment: I don't have enough points to submit comments, but you may want to keep an eye on this question, which talks about the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993792/python-command-line-arguments-ignored-for-standard-user-win-7

Comment: Thank you, that looks like exactly the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks completely normal to me. It's the command you invoke that receives and interprets your arguments. Apparantly django-admin.py
takes exception to your arguments "start-admin" and "batadase".

Comment: That exact command has worked in the past. This is just an example, certain other attempts have failed as well (usually python files)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880540/python-command-line-arguments-windows

I needed to add %* to my the registry in for opening python files.